Arc cosine of the negative cosine
I'm trying to simplify the following equation
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}(2\cos^{-1}(-\cos x)  - \sin(2\cos^{-1}(-\cos x)))$$
with $0 \le x \le \pi$.
The negative sign in $\cos^{-1}(-\cos x)$ is what is confusing me.

what is the number whose cosine is the opposite of the cosine of $x$? Draw a picture.

$-\cos x = \cos (\pi - x) = \cos (\pi + x)=\cos(\pi \pm x + 2k\pi)$ and so if $\cos w = -\cos x$ then $w =\pi +x$ or $\pi -x$ or $\pi \pm x \pm 2k\pi)$.  As $0\le \arccos w \le \pi$ we will have $\arccos(-\cos x) = \arccos(\pi -x, \pi + x, \pi \pm x \pm 2k\pi)=\pi -x, \pi + x, \pi \pm x \pm 2k\pi$, which ever one of them is in the correct range of values.  As $0\le \arccos \theta \le \pi$ and $0 \le x \le \pi$ the only one in range is $0 \le \pi -x \le \pi$.   So $\arccos(-\cos x)=\arccos(\pi -x) = \pi -x$.

The $\cos$ function is bijective when defined from $[0,\pi]$ to $[-1,1]$ so its inverse $\arccos$ is usually defined from $[-1,1] \to [0,\pi]$.
Now, if $x\in [0,\pi]$ then $\pi-x\in [0,\pi]$ also, which means that $\arccos(\cos(\pi-x)) = \pi - x$, but $\cos(\pi-x) = \cos(\pi)\cos(x)-\sin(\pi)\sin(x) = -\cos(x)$
Then $$\arccos(-\cos(x)) = \arccos(\cos(\pi-x))=\pi-x$$
when $x\in[0,\pi]$

I must apologize for accidentally editing your answer, when I was simply trying to provide my own separate answer.  I tried to roll my editing back to your intended answer.  Please double check whether I have correctly restored your intended answer, editing as needed.

The $\text{arccos}$ function has as its domain the interval $~[-1,1],~$ and has as its range the interval $~[0,\pi].~$
I am going to dispense with any attempt at elegance, and attack the problem one slow, careful step at a time.
Let $~\alpha~$ denote $~\arccos[\cos(x)],~$ and 
let $~\beta~$ denote $~\arccos[-\cos(x)].~$
First, let's be clear on what you are being asked to evaluate:
$$2\beta - \sin(2\beta) ~: ~0 \leq x \leq \pi. \tag1 $$
Since I am dispensing with any attempt at elegance, I will divide the analysis into two cases, depending on whether $~\cos(x) \geq 0,~$ or $~\cos(x) < 0.~$  Then, for each case, I will endeavor to express the math expression in (1) above in terms of $~x, \sin(x),~$ and $~\cos(x).~$
At the end of my analysis, I will make no attempt to collapse the cases into one overall expression.  This strikes me as pointless, and providing a separate expression for each of the two cases seems perfectly valid to me.

$\underline{\text{Case 1:} ~\cos(x) \geq 0}$
Here, $~\alpha \in [0,\pi/2]~$ and
$\beta = \pi - \alpha \implies$ 
$~2\beta = 2\pi - 2\alpha.$
Also, you have that $~\alpha = x.$
Therefore, $~\beta = \pi - x \implies 2\beta = 2\pi - 2x.$
Therefore, the expression in (1) above translates to
$$(2\pi - 2x) - \sin(2\pi - 2x)$$
$$= (2\pi - 2x) - [\sin(2\pi)\cos(2x) - \sin(2x)\cos(2\pi)]$$
$$= (2\pi - 2x) + \sin(2x)$$
$$= (2\pi - 2x) + 2\sin(x)\cos(x).$$

$\underline{\text{Case 2:} ~\cos(x) < 0}$
Here, $~\alpha \in (\pi/2,\pi]~$ and $~\cos(\beta) > 0 \implies $ 
$\beta \in [0,\pi/2),~$ and therefore, again, 
$\beta = \pi - \alpha \implies 2\beta = 2\pi - 2\alpha.$
Further, you once again have that $~\alpha = x.$
Therefore, since the formulas for $~\beta~$ in terms of $~\alpha~$ and $~\alpha~$ in terms of $~x~$ are identical to the Case 1 formulas, you have that all of the Case 1 analysis also applies to Case 2.
Therefore, the expression in (1) above again translates to
$$= (2\pi - 2x) + 2\sin(x)\cos(x).$$

Recall that $\cos^{-1}$ is a function from $[-1,1]$ to $[0,\pi]$ and it gives values in $[0,\pi/2]$ if $x\in[0,1]$ and in $[\pi/2,\pi]$ if $x\in[-1,0]$.
Now, if $x\in[0,\pi/2]$, then $\cos(x)\in[0,1]$ and so $-\cos(x)\in[-1,0]$. Thus, $\cos^{-1}(-\cos(x))\in[-\pi/2,\pi]$. Note that $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)$ and $\pi-x\in[\pi/2,\pi]$ so we can say
$$\cos^{-1}(-\cos(x))=\pi-x$$
You can repeat the same for the case when $x\in[\pi/2,\pi]$ and find that the same holds.
Hope this helps. :)
